# php profiling with names in the url "mod_rewrite"

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, profile

am creating a website for a company in `php` i need to create to every member his profile page 
like facebook's url

```
www.mywebsite.com/my.name
```

not like this:

```
www.mywebsite.com/?profile_id=65497
```

any ideas ??

Comment: nothing :D but still trying

Comment: Like [prior research](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+php%20mod_rewrite%20user%20name%20instead%20of%20profile%20id) ?

Comment: :) Note that there is a website called google. I found this: http://wettone.com/code/clean-urls

Answer (score 1):

I asume you are aware that this can only be done if you have some source that maps ids to names. `mod_rewrite` can look up strings in a lookup table and use the result in a substitution.

For example suppose you have a file that contains the name to id mappings.

```
# Mapping of names to UserIDs
Bill.Gates    100
Barack.Obamaq 101
Arsan.Gamal   102
```

You could then add the following to your apache config:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap UserIDs   txt:/path/to/userids.txt
RewriteRule /(.*)   /?profile_id=${UserIDs:$1|NOTFOUND}   [PT]
```

Now when a request comes for /Bill.Gates the part after the / is captured in a regex back reference, and used to look up a value in userids.txt. This value is than used in you substitution.

There are other possibilities. If your usernames and IDs exist in a database you can use a database query in a RewriteMap. More info on what you can do with RewriteMaps, and how to do it can be found in the manual here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html